# connected subsets of a set of vertices

Tags: combinatorics

I am struggeling with the following combinatorial problem:

Suppose you have $n$ vertices $1,2,\ldots,n$. Successive numbers / vertices are considered as neighbours, e.g. the neighbours of 3 are 1 and 2.

Suppose $i<n$. How many possibilities are there to take a subset of $i$ vertices such that these $i$ vertices are connected (in the sense of succesively neighbors)

Example: $n$ vertices and you take $i=2$. Then you have $n-1$ possibilities, i.e. (1,2),(2,3),...,$(n-1,n)$.

You would help me if you just point out some reference to me where similiar problems are considered!

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried $i=3$, $i=4$, etc.? Do you see a pattern?

Comment: The neighbors of $3$ are $1$ and $2$? Are the neighbors of $k$ all the vertices smaller than $k$?

Answer (score 0):

To take $i$ consecutive numbers, it suffices to take the first of them, that is between $1$ and $n-i+1$. Thus, there are $n-i+1$ possibilities.

Comment: Ah I did not formulate my question right. Of course this was trivial but i meant the following: Suppose you have n vertices 1,2,…,n. 
Suppose $i<n$. How many possibilities are there to take a subset of $i$ vertices and put them at positions 1,...,n such that $j<i$ vertices are connected (in one component of size $j$) and the left vertices are isolated ? Any literature recommendations on problems like this?